# Restrict outgoing calls

Tags: 8.1

I'm searching for a way to limit outgoing calls to whitelisted numbers.

It should be possible to remotely modify that whitelist.

I've already tried to push a policy to the device using Microsoft Intune which should disable the phone app with the following attempts:

- Disable every app NOT in that List: OneDrive
- Disable the app with the id 5B04B775-356B-4AA0-AAF8-6491FFEA5611 (taken from http://msicc.net/?p=3470)

but none of them worked. My hope was to simply replace the default app with a custom one that supports whitelists.

Any ideas?